# Warning: Middleware for RTK-Query API at reducerPath "api" has not been added to the store

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

I am trying to add a custom middleware to a store already using RTK Queries.
But I get the "Warning: Middleware for RTK-Query API at reducerPath "api" has not been added to the store." error at runtime, although I did add the api middleware.
Here is my store.ts file:

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { apiSlice } from './apiSlice'
import { homeModeReducer, workingReducer, bannersReducer, latestEventDataReducer } from './reducers/reducers'
import { useDispatch, useSelector, TypedUseSelectorHook } from 'react-redux'
import { latestMiddleware } from './middleware'

const reducer = combineReducers({
    [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
    mode: homeModeReducer,
    working: workingReducer,
    banners: bannersReducer,
    latestEventData: latestEventDataReducer
})

const store = configureStore({
    reducer,
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(latestMiddleware).concat(apiSlice.middleware)
})

export default store
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof reducer>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>()
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
```

and my middleware is defined as:

```
import { Middleware } from 'redux'
import { RootState } from './store'

export const latestMiddleware: Middleware<
    {}, // Most middleware do not modify the dispatch return value
    RootState
> = storeApi => next => action => {
    console.log(action.type)
    return storeApi.getState() // correctly typed as RootState
}
```

It compiles correctly but fails at runtime. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `latestMiddleware` is not calling `next(action)`, which means that the next middleware (and finally, the reducer) will never be executed.

Comment: Also, you don't really need that lastestMiddleware. If you need the current store state, just use a thunk: `const currentState = dispatch((dispatch, getState) => getState())`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74125530/middleware-for-rtk-query-api-at-reducerpath-error-only-while-running-rtl-tes