# Middleware for RTK-Query API at reducerPath Error - "only" while running RTL tests

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, react-testing-library, redux-toolkit

I am trying to migrate my redux store to RTK and RTK query - and making my RTL tests work with it

I am going for a gradual re-write - transforming each reducer 1 by 1.

I have re-created my store used in the application - replacing createStore with a configureStore - and added the middleware for api handling like this:

```
import { vendorPaymentsApiSlice } from './vendorPaymentsAPISlice';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   users: userReducer,
   [vendorPaymentsApiSlice.reducerPath]: vendorPaymentsApiSlice.reducer
})

//vendorPaymentsApiSlice.reducerPath is set to "vendorpaymentsApi"

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: [
    ...getDefaultMiddleware(),
    sagaMiddleware,
    vendorPaymentsApiSlice.middleware,
  ],
});
```

This setup is working fine in the real application. The middleware linking for api is working as expected.

For my tests i am using a mock store - which replaces history with mockHistory but it is mostly the same code- same rootReducer and same middleware array.

In my tests I have written a msw interceptor for the api call -
and the interceptor is getting called:

[image]

but as soon as that happens - I am getting this error message:

```
Warning: Middleware for RTK-Query API at reducerPath "vendorpaymentsApi" has not been added to the store.
Features like automatic cache collection, automatic refetching etc. will not be available.
```

Because of this - the data setting in redux from the api is failing .

I tried many variations of adding the middleware after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71249368/warning-middleware-for-rtk-query-api-at-reducerpath-api-has-not-been-added-to) and tried

```
getDefaultMiddleware().concat([
    sagaMiddleware,
    vendorPaymentsApiSlice.middleware,
  ])
```

but it's still not working.

Wanted some help to understand why the linking of this api is not happening with the tests.

Thanks a lot for reading this

Answer (score 1):

the correct way of setting up your middleware would be

```
  middleware: getDefaultMiddleware => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(sagaMiddleware).concat(vendorPaymentsApiSlice.middleware),
```

but I'm honestly not 100% sure if that's your issue. Are you really using this store in your tests (you should!) and not some kind of mock store?

---

You have given the api a `reducerPath` of `"vendorpaymentsApi"` and then you mount it in your store as `vpApi`.
Either change the `reducerPath` option to `vpApi` or change `vpApi: vpApi.reducer` to `vendorpaymentsApi: vpApi.reducer`

Comment: thanks for the answer -  but i had vpApi just to mask my original code, 
i have updated my code samples to show the exact code which i have written.

i am using reference to reducerPath everywhere -

Comment: I edited something about the middleware in

Comment: I am re-creating the mock store for my tests - but for recreating the mock store also - i'm using the exact same code which is in store.
the reason for mock store is that i am replacing history with mocked history

Comment: i was able to find the answer to this problem - thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I tried to recreate this error in a simpler repo [here](https://github.com/probosckie/redux-toolkit-testing-with-rtl)

The problem was not in the middleware declaration in configure store - but in another pattern which was being used.

Pattern: "Instead of creating a new store every time while testing a redux connected component as described [here](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests) - use a store singleton and dispatch an action to reset the store to initial data passed from the test"

As shown in [this file](https://github.com/probosckie/redux-toolkit-testing-with-rtl/blob/main/src/reducers.js)

But the problem was that I had forgotten to set the api reducer in my default empty state which was being used as base - before shallow merging the passed data:

[image]

I had ommitted the "api" key in this which was causing this error - and once I added it back - the error went away.